# Get list of all stocks ever listed on NASDAQ

Tags: market-data, trading, nasdaq

I'm looking to compile a list of all stocks/symbols **ever** listed on the NASDAQ, not just the currently listed stocks. Alternatively, a list of all delisted stocks would also suffice.

Preferably, I'm looking for a free solution but am certainly also interested in any paid suggestions ya'll might have.

I'm not fussy about the format.

Any ideas and help would be greatly appreciated, cheers!

Comment: http://www.crsp.com/products/documentation/nasdaq-information-codes ? Why isn't CRSP sufficient?

Comment: For accuracy CRSP is the best solution, although it may not be available/free to you